# Ember Template will render but won't display inside app

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

[Related Topic](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/most-common-reasons-ember-templates-wont-render-inside-rails-app/1486)

So in the link above is a topic related to what I am trying to figure out. but I'm not sure.
Here is whats going on, my index template is being rendered but visually I can't see anything. I don't have any JS errors and it works just fine. When I inspect it all the code shows up but FOR some reason i cant see(visually see the code thats rendered) it. the only thing that shows is the navigation. which is not part of the template.

So I though well take the whole thing out and call the {{outlet}} last...NOPE still saw nothing but the navigation.

I'm trying not to be vague Im new to ember and stackoverflow. Not sure if the link to the actual problem is enough. let me know if any further explanation is needed

Comment: The best thing to do would be to reproduce a simple use case using jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you i thought i deleted my question i did discover it was my css more specifically I had to set a style on `[id*='ember'] {}` so that when the app started it would play well with my framework

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the http://www.redberryapp.com/phonegap/css/redberry.css

please have a look at the example below,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kanobobe/1/edit

it has been created from the code/files found in www.redberryapp.com  and it seems to display the content if

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.redberryapp.com/phonegap/css/redberry.css">`

stays commented out. The template always gets rendered, but it is not displayed if the specific stylesheet is active.